# Batch file - start program with admin rights

Tags: boot, batch, administrator

I have a .bat file in my startup folder:

```
d:
cd\
cd TrueCrypt
truecrypt /ll /p "" /q /v d:\MYO
```

Is there a way to start TrueCrypt with admin right?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: If UAC is enabled, you should follow the answer here: http://superuser.com/a/372436/24500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `runas`

```
d:
cd\
cd TrueCrypt
runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator truecrypt /ll /p "" /q /v d:\MYO
```

Comment: This no longer works starting with Vista/7. On non-domain joined machines, this will work, as the built-in Admin account is granted Admin Approval mode.  Domain joined machines will have their built-in Admin Account disabled and this will not work.  In general though, `runas` does not equal admin rights if UAC is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If it is run as a Startup Script it runs with Elevated permissions (at least in XP and earlier Not sure on Vista/7) This is set under Computer Configuration-Windows Setting-Scripts(Startup/Shutdown)

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7 Pro on a non-domain system.  Thanks for the tip, I used gpedit.msc to add the script to my user account and now it runs as admin on startup.