# How do I elevate permissions from within a batch script in Windows 7 or 2008?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch file - start program with admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/206378/batch-file-start-program-with-admin-rights)

I'm writing a batch script that requires administrator permissions to execute, so to start it I need to right-click and select "Run as Administrator". Is there a way to elevate permissions form within the script instead, like "su" in *nix?

Comment: If batch files could elevate themselves and circumvent UAC, then malware would have a heyday. :)

Comment: @techie007: This is true. But usually when folks say they need to elevate a script, it doesn't mean to circumvent UAC. Batchfiles have no built in method of even invoking a command that requires admin privileges. And the linked duplicate needs to be updated as that no longer works with UAC.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of triggering UAC dialog box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only a batch file? AFAIK, impossible.  You'll need to fire off a VBscript or JScript, which can use the Shell.Execute.

You can look at some examples [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/185/1/VBScripts-and-UAC-elevation.html) or donwload the [Elevate Powertoys](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.technet.com%2Fb%2Felevationpowertoys%2F&ei=pYf7TvPuIqThsQLmvJm6AQ&usg=AFQjCNEiKJasxznGUN_l8yK2_c7jr0_rbQ), which are premade VBscripts and batchfiles you can use.

Also included in the Elevate Powertoys are examples on how to self elevate a batfile.